# Stuck in Recovery login after building and loading the Linux kernel

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, kernel

This is the first time am working on Raspberry Pi boards, and I have ordered and received a new Raspberry Pi 3 board, I have installed the default Raspbian OS. Now I wanted to update kernel and I followed the instructions provided in the link [CROSS-COMPILING-KERNEL](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) from Raspberry official site. After updating the SD card when I load my card in to the Pi board, I see that the board is not booting up and I see that am stuck at this point (when I see the logs in the uart console).

```
Welcome to the rescue system
recovery login:
```

But the keyboard does not seem to work. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you compiling the kernel for some particular reason? Why not just update to the current 4.4.11 kernel?

Comment: My intention was to learn how to do board bring up activities. And ultimately to install embedded Linux on Pi.

Comment: @goldilocks: I figured out that if I dont connect the HDMI cable or monitor to the board am seeing the above situation on my Uart terminal. And what ever I enter via keyboard was also not getting accepted. There should be a configuration that I can set so that Pi will not wait for a valid pulse or something from HDMI and proceed to boot ? so that I can work with headless Pi board.

Comment: At this point I would say there are things you need to accept about reality, such as the fact that you have been unable to cross-compile a working kernel.  If you get the exact same symptoms with a stock distro kernel, that's a different issue and you should ask a different question.  Otherwise, you should forget about this and move on.  Just because there is a recipe somewhere does not mean all you have to do is spend a few hours in the kitchen, and voila, you have baked a delicacy.  It could also come out as a total mess. What went wrong? It may take many tries before you get it right.

Comment: It may also be that what you are trying to do simply requires more skill and knowledge than you actually have right now.  Not everybody can do anything just because they want to -- again, this is reality.  If you had to have surgery and right before you were anesthetized the doctor said, "Well, actually I'm not a doctor but I read a blog article about it..." you might rightly assume you will never wake up again.

Comment: Actually, am able to cross compile the kernel 4.4.13 and my Raspberry Pi  3 is up and running with the kernel that I built. Now, at least I have source of the kernel what my device is running. But I was wondering why did I face the problem initially that was actually the reason for creating this question and accidentally found the same issue when I forgot to connect HDMI cable to the board. Thought I will update the question so that somebody reading this will know I came out of this problem. :) Thank you again for help, and for those good words about moving on learning new things.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

It's not clear that you are missing anything.  Unless you built in an initial ram disk (which is unnecessary and generally pointless on the pi), this at least indicates the kernel booted and accessed the root filesystem.

Did you try then logging in? You don't mention an OS, but having this happen on Raspbian might be a little awkward because if it requires root there.

I don't remember the last time I had to use "recovery mode" so I am not sure if it is asking for a log in name there, or just the root password.  First try the Rasbian default user name `pi` and password `raspberry`.  If that works you should be able to run the commands below that way, but if you still end up needing to login as root, keep reading (it will be clear if this is a username/password login, because after you enter something, it will ask for the password; if it does not and just says you failed, then it is just a root password, and you will need to set it first).

By default there isn't a root password, and you can't login as `root`.  If that's the case, you can set it up so there isn't a password but you can login ([see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168422/25985); that refers to a case where there is a root password set and it appears in `/etc/shadow` as a long string, but in this case it is just `*` -- remove that so you end up with the same undefined field, `::`, then there is no password and just hitting enter should work).  Note do not try and set a password this way, it will not work; you can just make it possible to log in without one (it might be possible if you understand the hashing method used, but let's not bother).

Anyway, if you can login one way or another, you can check what kernel is being used with:

```
uname -r
```

If you added a string suffix to the version in configuration it should then be obvious.  If you didn't and you build a different version than was otherwise available, it should be obvious.  Otherwise, try:

```
uname -a
```

This will show the kernel type (`Linux`), the host name, that version string, then a build number (e.g., `#2`) *and a date and time*.  That was from the machine it was built on during the time it was built, so that should be decisive.

An easy thing to forget especially if you are cross-compiling is *to install the modules*.  The pi kernel's default configuration has enough drivers to access the root fs built in, but if you forgot to put the modules in the appropriate `/lib/modules` directory it will have trouble right off the bat, which might explain "emergency mode".

Comment: I have installed default Raspbian OS from NOOBS card and this is my kernel version: `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`. After that I cross compiled the Kernel as per the instructions mentioned in this [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md). Copied the new kernel and device tree on to the SD card, and inserted the SD card on to Pi, and rebooted the Pi. I noticed that am stuck at recovery.

Comment: I will work on your suggestions and will let you know how it goes. thanks.

Comment: It may actually want a *user name* then a password -- try the default "pi" and password "raspberry" there.   I will edit the answer a bit about this.

Comment: Right, I use that credentials if the board boots fine. But when I was stuck in `recovery login:` any input that am providing from keyboard was not getting reflected on the console.

Comment: Hmmph.   I'm not sure if the USB and HID (keyboard, mouse) drivers are built in, so if you didn't install the modules as mentioned in the last paragraph, the keyboard might not work.

Comment: I looked at the default configuration and I am pretty sure enough stuff for a generic USB mouse and keyboard should be built right in and not require anything from `/lib/modules`, so unless you changed that in the build configuration, it is some more serious issue.  If you haven't built linux kernels much in the past, there are a lot of potential pitfalls.

Comment: Yes sir, I just followed the steps mentioned in this [cross_compile_steps](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) and the same steps are provided in the GIT sources too. So I believe there could be something else that I would have missed. Can you please take a quick look at the** CROSS -COMPILING** section from that documentation and advice that the procedure I followed is correct approach to build and load a kernel on Pi. Please !

Comment: Did you catch the part in those instructions where it says the Raspbian root filesystem on NOOBs, where you should install the modules to, is the "7th" one, not the 2nd? (As in `sdb7` there; although there are only 5 partitions, I think they are numbered this way because DOS MBR formatted devices can only have 4 "primary" partitions, this appears to have two, numbered 1 and 2, with 2 divided into 3 "secondary" partitions, 5, 6, 7).  Which ever one it is, double check the `/lib/modules` directory.